# What is the difference between an Anti-Ship Drone and an Anti-Ship Beam Drone?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

They both cost 50, require 2 power. Their flavor text is nigh identical:

> Powerful Drone that continually attacks the enemy ship.
>   Combat Drone that repeatedly attacks with a small beam weapon.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Anti-Ship Drone is armed with a laser, which does damage to a single room targeted randomly by the drone.  It also takes the shields down one level if it hits a shield..

The Anti-Ship Beam Drone is armed with a beam weapon, which does damage to multiple rooms along the path of the beam, but which does not affect shields at all.  Instead, shields affect the beam, in that each level of shield reduces the damage of the beam. Since the Anti-Ship Beam Drone only does 1 damage per room, even a single active shield can render the Anti-Ship Beam Drone completely useless.

Comment: And since the beam does one damage per room, even a single layer of shields will render the Beam Drone completely ineffective.

Comment: The beam drone seems to usually target only one room, but the fact that it never misses still makes it better in some situations.