# How do drones choose their targets?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

How do anti-ship and beam-drones choose their targets? Is it always random or is there some pattern or some other method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an Anti-Ship Drone and an Anti-Ship Beam Drone?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84541/what-is-the-difference-between-an-anti-ship-drone-and-an-anti-ship-beam-drone)

Comment: He's not asking about the difference between them, he's asking how either type picks its targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a drone chooses its target per random.

Comment: Ok what should help, link to the wiki which states it is random

Comment: That'd be a good start.

Comment: By the way, neither of the main wikis says how drones choose targets.

Comment: Doesn't the game itself say it's random?

Comment: [This question][1] accepted response has for given that the drones attack randomly.


  [1]: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84541/what-is-the-difference-between-an-anti-ship-drone-and-an-anti-ship-beam-drone