# How does a System Repair Drone choose the order of repairs?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When there is only 1 system damaged, it makes its way there (at a leisurely pace) to effect repairs. But when the fertilizer hits the fan, they seem to spend more time running to the opposite end of the ship, and less time fixing broken systems.

1. *How does a System Repair Drone choose the order of repairs?*
2. *Is there a way to direct it to a different system, after it has set a destination?*

I found: *[How do drones choose their targets?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102755/how-do-drones-choose-their-targets)*, but it only talks about Anti-Ship Drones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [one of the wikis,](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Drones) the System Repair Drone "Gives System and Sub-System rooms priority, repairing rooms in the order that they were damaged."

Comment: Hmmph. That's a very unoptimized solution.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @tugs answer

There is no way to direct it to a specific room, other than sending it out multiple times.

So for example if your weapons room was hit first and then your FTL drive, the system repair drone will fix your weapons system. Another example, if your doors system was hit first and then your FTL drive, the drone will then go to the FTL system room first.

Comment: Does powering the drone down/up affect the order of repairs?